# Android ListView Adapter - Hide Items

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a android listView wich will filled like this:

```
final ListView userList = (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.userList);
UserListAdapter adapter = new UserListAdapter(context, userItemList,
getActivity());
userList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the UserListAdapter looks like this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_item_list, null);
}
final TextView txtButtonFollow = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
if(user == "showed") {
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}else {
    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
return convertView;
```

For some reason all user buttons will be showed (first), but if i scroll the list up and down and "reenter" the user-item, the buttons are hided (this is what i need).

Does anyone had the same problem? 
Is it not possible to hide elements "on-scroll"?
Do i have to setup two user_item_list (one with the button and the other one without the button)?

Edit: Here full getView():

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    UserItem userItem = userItems.get(position);
    RelativeLayout userListItemMain = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userListItemMain);
    String isContact = userItem.getIsContact();

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    final TextView txtButton = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    if(isContact) {
        txtButton .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        txtButton .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Implement view holder pattern and to compare strings use `.equals`

Comment: Your if/else statement is kinda... useless in its current state

Comment: post the whole adapter code

Comment: you have conertView, but where is the button initialization?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

Comment: I've edited the Code and yes the if/else statement was useless, but this was/is not the problem.

Comment: @Calimero edited if statement also is not right. Its a string not a boolean value

Comment: @Raghunandan: This was just a dummy-statement and had nothing to do, with the problem.

Comment: @Calimero it should be relevant to what you are doing or what you want. If you don't want to post a production related code. Change the dats but keep the logic the same. This will avoid unnecessary attention on not so important piece of cod

Answer (score 3):

You can change this

```
 UserListAdapter adapter = new UserListAdapter(context, userItemList,getActivity());
```

to

```
UserListAdapter adapter = new UserListAdapter(userItemList,getActivity());
```

`getActivity()` will give you context.

Change the adapter constructor accordingly

Use a `ViewHolder` Pattern

```
public static class ViewHolder
{
     TextView txtButton ;
}
```

In getView

```
  ViewHolder holder;
  if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_item_list, null);
        holder.txtButton  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button); 
        convertView.setTag(holder) 
    } else {

         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } 
    UserItem userItem = userItems.get(position);
    String isContact = userItem.getIsContact();

    if(isContact.equals("showed")) {
    holder.txtButton .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }else{
     holder.txtButton .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }

return convertView;
```

Your if statement

```
 if(isContact) { // makes no sense. isContact is not boolean
```

Comment: Okay, got it ;). Thank you, this helped me a lot.